# basic Multithread in C++ ( The execute order)

Tags: c++

When you have following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

#define NUM_THREADS     5

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
   long tid;
   tid = (long)threadid;
   cout << "Hello World! Thread ID, " << tid << endl;
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main ()
{
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   int rc;
   int i;
   for( i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ ){
      cout << "main() : creating thread, " << i << endl;
      rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, 
                          PrintHello, (void *)i);
      if (rc){
         cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;
         exit(-1);
      }
   }
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

the out put will be 
main() : creating thread, 0
main() : creating thread, 1
main() : creating thread, 2
main() : creating thread, 3
main() : creating thread, 4
Hello World! Thread ID, 0
Hello World! Thread ID, 1
Hello World! Thread ID, 2
Hello World! Thread ID, 3
Hello World! Thread ID, 4
```

I am wondering why it's not

```
main() : creating thread, 0
Hello World! Thread ID, 0
main() : creating thread, 1
Hello World! Thread ID, 1
....
```

Why we create the thread, it execute immediately?

Another question Thread 0,1,2,3,4, is that possible those threads execute in random order? for example, output will be

```
Hello World! Thread ID, 1
Hello World! Thread ID, 4
Hello World! Thread ID, 0
Hello World! Thread ID, 2
Hello World! Thread ID, 3
```

Thanks a lot for answering!

Comment: I Mean when we create the thread pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, 
                          PrintHello, (void *)i); why not it executes immediately, then it gives the output before we create the second thread

Comment: Threads execute asynchronously, so it's up to the operating system's scheduler to decide what order to run them in.  You can't count on them executing in any particular order.

Comment: Unless you use synchronization. But, without it, don't take for given any execution order.

Comment: If you want them to execute in order (synchronously), don't use threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of threaded systems is that it allows actions to run in parallel. What that ultimately means is that you have a number of tasks that you would like to do at the same time and you don't care about the relative ordering at which parts of these tasks are done.

If you want tasks to occur in exactly one order, then ask yourself what the point of threads are and what you are trying to get out of them. If you have 4 threads, but at any given moment only one of them is acting and the others are waiting for their turn to act, then you might as well have had your program execute in one thread.

Threads operate on the assumption that ordering doesn't matter. The guarantee that the Operating System provides to you is that, barring any synchronization primitives, the Operating System will give enough time for each thread (through scheduling) to make progress on whatever action it is supposed to execute.

A call like `pthread_create` tells the operating system to spawn a new thread which will execute something. You have no control over:

1. When the operating system will spawn the thread, or
2. After the thread is spawned, at which point the operating system will give it a timeslice to execute enough instructions to get to the print statement.